# Dónde debo guardar mi TOKEN en mi FRONTEND?

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, tokens

Tengo este código en mi backend nodejs hecho con express, en un controlador llamado: user.js, y lo exporto al archivo enrutador: user.js

```
const connection = require("../connection")
const bcryp = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const register = (request, response) => {
    let userToken = null
    let user = request.body
    console.log(user)
    user.contra = bcryp.hashSync(user.contra, 10)
    connection.query('INSERT INTO users (nombre, email, contra) VALUES (?,?,?)', [user.nombre, user.email, user.contra], (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error al registrar el usuario')
        } else {
             jwt.sign({user}, 'D1eG○', (error, token) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error al generar el token del usuario')
                } else {
                    userToken = token
                    user.token = userToken
                    response.json(user)
                }
            })
        } 

    })

}


module.exports = {
    register
}
```

Y en mi frontend tengo un formulario donde consumo la api con FETCH

```
formulario.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const newUser = {
        nombre: formulario.nombre.value,
        email: formulario.email.value,
        contra: formulario.contra.value
    }
    console.log(newUser)
    enviar('http://localhost:3000/users/signin', newUser)
})

const enviar = async (url, user) => {
    let result = null
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    switch (response.status) {
        case 200:
            result = await response.json()
            console.log(result)
            break;
    
        default:
            console.log('no controlado')
            break;
    }
    return result
}
```

MI PREGUNTA ES:
Donde debo guardar el TOKEN, luego de que el backend reciba los datos del nuevo usuario los registre en la BBDD, y me retorne el TOKEN para estar autorizado y seguir navegando en el sitio. Pensaba en guardarlo en un objeto javascript, en un archivo autorizacion.js, pero no se que tan seguro puedo ser eso, por ahi lei en un LOCALSTORAGE, necesito su ayuda.

Comment: Si se guarda en un objeto JS el token se perderá al actualizar la página o cerrar el navegador. Para que persista puedes guardarlo en el localStorage.

Comment: Claro, tienes razon, habia leido ademas que tengo que enviar el token por el header de la respuesta, eso es mas recomendable ?

Comment: Por lo general el token de autenticación se envía  al cliente en el cuerpo de la respuesta al hacer el login. Y luego el cliente envía el token en el header de cada petición para acceder a los recursos.

Comment: Para persistir el token puedes almacenarlo en local storage, session storage o las cookies. Cada opción tiene sus particularidades.

Comment: Gracias, por sus respuestas. Hare como me dicen.

Comment: Tengo la misma duda, ya que yo estoy tratando de pasar el token desde mi Fronted pero al parecer el middleware no lo reconoce; me interesaba mucho tu pregunta para ver las respuestas

Comment: Hola Juan, verifica que tu middleware (backend) realmente reciba el token, revisa el header del request o por ultimo el body